# The loop runs twice in a single run

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, while-loop

This problem is from https://www.hackerrank.com/ and link to it is https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-list/problem .
In the below code while loop is running twice as according to question we need to enter Q, Q times an operation to perform in the Array Declared. For this, i am running twice the loop so that I can get the desired result.

```
import java.util.*;

public class javaList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        int i, x;
        ArrayList L = new ArrayList(N);
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            L.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        int Q = sc.nextInt();
        i = 0;
        // for normal running i have multiplied Q by 2 so that i can get the results
        while (i < Q * 2) {
            System.out.println("Loop: " + i);
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            int sz = L.size();
            // code for checking insert
            if (s.equals("Insert")) {
                x = sc.nextInt();
                int y = sc.nextInt();
                //if the position i am looking exists then just replace
                // i need to insert at index x of array L but array.size() gives one more than the last index
                if ((sz - 1) >= x) {
                    L.add(x, y);
                }
                //if the position i am looking does not exist then create
                else {
                    for (int j = sz; j <= x; j++) {
                        //add number to desired place
                        if (j == x)
                            L.add(y);
                            //in between the two endings of array and insertion adding default value 0
                        else
                            L.add(0);
                    }
                }
                //checking code for Delete
            } else if (s.equals("Delete")) {
                x = sc.nextInt();
                //if the desired location exists then only replace
                if ((sz - 1) >= x) {
                    L.remove(x);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < L.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(L.get(i) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to Know why the loop is running twice in a single run.

Comment: I see multiple loops in the code. Which one is running twice and how many times do you expect it to run?

Comment: Sorry sir, I would have made methods for a particular task.

Comment: The While loop.

Comment: `while (i < Q * 2)` will cause the loop to execute `Q * 2` times. Is this what you want?

Comment: for the question, I did so.    while(i < Q)       If i give Q=2. Normally i should run loop 2 times but it asks for operation only once.

Comment: please sir, run the code then you would understand what i mean.

Comment: I ran your code, the loop runs 4 times if Q = 2. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @iheanyi if Q = 2 then it should ask operations Insert or Delete 4 times as of my code. But it asks only 2 times. Simply that is my problem.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem. Because you have very little interaction, you don't realize when your program is still running or prompting for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from discussion in the comments, you've stated that your question is:

> if Q = 2 then it should ask operations Insert or Delete 4 times as of my code. But it asks only 2 times. Simply that is my problem

First, you may not fully understand your own program flow. Before the while loop, you need to enter three sets of values, a value for N, values for L, and a value for Q.

Once you enter your while loop, you will be prompted for a value for s (which it seems you intend to be either "Insert" or "Delete"). However, the first time around, it will get an empty string and s will be "\n". Why? Because for N, L, and Q, the user will enter values as follows:

[value] [ENTER]

The return key is itself a value. So, in the input buffer (assuming Q = 2), is "2\n". When your code runs to get s `String s = sc.nextLine();` it will see the next line symbol and skip prompting user for input.

Because s is not "Insert" or "Delete", it will skip those the first time around. You will then be prompted to enter a value for "s" after the start next loop.

To help you realize what's going on, I suggest adding statements everywhere you ask users to enter a value, like `System.out.println("Enter a value for Q:");`

This will help you keep track of program flow.

Comment: Thanks, I understood what i was missing. But what should i do if i don't want to print anything? As you have said System.out.println("Enter a value for Q:"); i many of question i am asked to get inputs directly without displaying any messages.

Comment: @MdMobshshirNayeem Generally, I suggest using the print statements while you are creating and testing your program. Once you are sure it works as expected, you can remove them before submitting the assignment. In this particular case, it seems you need to have some amount of prompt - there are too many different values that require input and the specific input or number of input changes depending on other values. For example, if I enter 1 for N, I only need to enter one additional value before Q. If I enter 3 for N, I'll need to give 3 additional values. This can be confusing w/o prompts.

Comment: @MdMobshshirNayeem Also, to ensure the user is prompted for s the first time in the loop, I'd suggest adding a `sc.next();` after `int Q = sc.nextInt();` This will consume any tokens left in the scanner after the user enters Q so that the scanner is empty and will wait for user input when it gets to `String s = sc.nextLine();`

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts. I finally understood the solution. I have learned this previously but never encountered, from today i think i will never forget this concept.

Comment: @MdMobshshirNayeem I'm glad I could help. I also want to recognize you for doing a good job posting a complete and working code example. Once I understood the issue you were having, that made it very easy for me to help.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is waaay to complicated. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0, n = scanner.nextInt(); i < n; i++) {
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }

    for (int i = 0, n = scanner.nextInt(); i < n; i++) {
        if (scanner.next().equals("Insert")) {
            list.add(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
        } else {
            list.remove(scanner.nextInt());
        }
    }

    String result = list.stream()
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the problem in reading the code.But your Solution gives the error. If i declare n=5 and want to insert  at index 7.